# Can I improve this logo design with any effects or filters?

Tags: logo, critique, filter

I've been asked to design a logo for a heritage trust. The logo must have a medieval cross as its centrepiece. However, whilst I'm a photographer with negligible graphic design experience I gave it a shot:

[image: original try]

It was a case of trying to combine the intricacy of the original Celtic knots with the simplicity of the best logos. It looks somewhat clumsy to me.

I then messed around with some filters in PS to try and roughen up the edges. The stamp filter (nothing else was used) seemed to give the best finish. The result is better but could it be improved on:

[image: filter added]

So, what I'm wondering is if anyone knows of a very quick filter or combination of filters that could be applied to the original "cross" image to give some "sparkle" to the original file? This is very vague, I know, but to an extent I'm going by feel here. Watercolor effect? Stone effect? Carte blanche rules.

Not a technical question and it sounds like a logo design on the cheap--which it is. But if someone has an idea that could quickly be applied to the file, I would be very grateful as this is an area I'm very inexperienced in. Even a suggestion to look at another logo that might provide me with ideas would be great? Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: Honestly the first image looks a lot better than the second. Is this the highest resolution version of the image you have?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow @Ray200. It looks like your question will result in only opinion based answers. Since the value of this site is in generating a knowledge base of solutions to problems, I don’t see this question as fitting the site scope. Essentially you are looking for design help - which is not wrong - but not a good fit for the format of  this site.

Comment: The more "filters" and "effects" you use on a logo, typically the less professional it appears.

Comment: @kontur I respectfully disagree. Our site encourages critiques and brainstorming. Opinion is 100% of graphic design and varying opinions improve quality of work. OPs post explains what he's attempted and is requesting feedback and tips. This is totally within the scope of the site. Take a look at how we handle critiques in the following link if you don't believe me.. https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372/how-to-handle-critiques

Comment: @LateralTerminal Cheers, haven’t actively visited and I remember those types of open ended requests used to be off topic. The ambiguity of the answers seems to agree, even if the rules don’t.

Comment: @kontur we specifically hate low quality questions where OP doesn't explain what they've already tried. We still have a problem with that. But this particular question is not too offending. It's amateurish but a good opportunity to teach the cheesiness of filters to the community.

Comment: I agree with @kontur - specific problem solving or direct pointed criticism are great! General "idea farming" is typically too broad.

Comment: @Scott idea farming is too broad I agree. But this particular question is just asking for advice on filters applied to his already completed image. He's stated what he's already tried and put decent effort into the question. I don't believe this question is too broad.

Comment: We simply disagree @LateralTerminal "advice on filters" could not be more broad and opinion-based in my view. *"....provide me with ideas"* is another indicator.

Comment: Hi Ray200, welcome to GDSE. Critique questions are a bit of a weird fit here, because they don't always match with our intended Q&A format so please have a look at our [guidelines for critique questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/682) if you haven't already. Thanks!

Comment: Not related to the logo design (I agree with others: lose the filters, keep it simple—and perhaps find a font with a bit more oomph or personality than Palatino), but shouldn’t it be _Eilean **Mòr**_?

Comment: I suggest asking this question on some place like https://www.reddit.com/r/design_critiques or https://www.reddit.com/r/Logo_Critique

Answer (score 8):

I second the comment on your post. The original image is better, to my eyes, than the "improved" version. With respect, I think your thinking is *back to front*.

Firstly, good job with the logo, considering you say you have little experience I think it's a reasonable job. But you should keep in mind that no filter, no quick trick, is going to make the original somehow "better".

Think about the classic logos...Coca-cola, Amazon...a million others, logos tend to be "vector" files... like your first example. Clean, high-contrast and uncluttered. (as well as visually appealing, on subject etc etc). So I would stop thinking what can be done to improve it "after the fact" and instead concentrate on what can be done to improve the original design.

Bearing in mind that this logo is going to need to be reproduced in colour and black and white, and also at multiple sizes including possibly down to 64x64 pixels or less, I think one immediate area for improvement is in reducing the complexity of the cross.

I do like what you've done with it, but I worry it will scale very effectively. I would start out by reducing the complexity there, and I would beef up the font to provide more balance with the cross. Perhaps something Medieval/Celtic but of course it would be easy to go "pastiche" by accident!

**The takeaway here is that no filter, no quick fix, is going to improve the original design.**

Answer (score 3):

Simplify the design. Start off my converting to a vector format - no logo should ever be done in a pixel format, since this will limit the use of the logo to that specific size or smaller sizes only.

Here is some things that come to mind:

- Reduce the detail of the top, left and right set-in crosses and floral decors; maybe use a simple cross or single leave in all of them; alternatively try completely removing them
- Make the celtic not less intricate; you could for example remove the entire middle of the three rings
- Remove the center circle and expand the size of the knot lines instead, opting for a single dominant visual element
- Overall look at the balance of white space and detail, and make sure you have clear shapes with equally little amount of detail all over
- Pick a font that somewhat reflects either the early christian scribal culture or resonates stone carved letters associated with celtic tombstones
- Integrate the wordmark to the logo and balance the size of text to logo

Use your imagination, not your tools. Start the design by drawing on paper, it will be much more fast to find what works and what doesn’t.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possiblities to filter

1) make it simpler

2) try to be arty by adding details; random and mimicking textures, light and thickness

If you are going to filter a logo to keep it as a logo, simplifying have a possiblity to be productive.

Making it more complex perhaps is useful when creating a derivative work which utilizes the logo as a subject - a T-shirt or scented candle, for example, if the original is still recognizable. If you are lucky, you make an illusion there's somewhere a real object which is shown one way in the logo and otherwise in the filtering result (see NOTE1)

Here is your original, a simplification and three "wanna be arty" filterings

[image]

I believe that the simplification could be a logo. It's fault is we know it's a filtering result. I tried to make the small details rounder like you have done, but to save all gaps and holes, even to make them bigger. The writing is thicker and taller. I think your simplification has made it too thin in many places.

The simplified version actually is more easily produceable with 1000 years old tools than your original, so it has at least one reason to stay alive until enough downvotes appear.

NOTE1: If that happens and you are going to use the result, be sure that you also have a nice story.

Answer (score 0):

First I want to say [I agree with the first answer here.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/107125/104169)

> The takeaway here is that no filter, no quick fix, is going to improve
> the original design.

And this comment

> The more "filters" and "effects" you use on a logo, typically the less
> professional it appears. – Scott

---

## If you insist on using a filter

**FIRST: We are working in Illustrator because logos need to be vector.**

I think the "Rough Pastels" under "Artistic Filters" is a good choice for this particular artwork. I like it because it adds a little bit of depth to it with the shading and it also makes it look a bit worn. Unlike the second image OP provided which just looks like a bad fax.

[image]

Even better if you apply it in Illustrator then you can keep everything vector. **You don't need Photoshop to use all the Photoshop filters.**

[image]

The benefit of doing it in Illustrator is that you can still modify the file with the filter over it.

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate why that particular filter a good choice for this particular artwork?

Comment: @kontur I like it because it adds a little bit of depth to it with it's shading and it also makes it look a bit worn. Unlike the second image OP provided which just looks like a bad fax.

Comment: I don't personally like the effect, but your answer definitely didn't warrant a downvote. Upvoted.

Comment: @LateralTerminal I was curious to hear your reasoning, since the justification behind an idea can generate more, whereas naming a filter will not. To my eye the filters adds only more noise. Additionally Rough Pastels imitates the shading result from drawing with chalk on textured paper — while Celtic knots have been reproduced on paper medium it is always the stone or fine metal designs these, too, reference, and would form a more authentic departure point for a texture. My downvote is, as this question and answer, opinion based — namely my view that your suggestion makes the logo look worse.

Comment: @kontur Have you gone through all the available filters yourself? There are no filters for " stone or fine metal designs" This filter looked the best out of all of them. That's why I chose it. Not because it's historically accurate. I doubt that's the first thing that will come to anyones mind when they see it. "Hmm is this artwork historically accurate? Back then people didn't paint crosses with pastel?" The average person isn't going to think that.

Comment: @kontur OP said "I then messed around with some filters in PS to try and roughen up the edges" If that's what he wanted to do this effect does it much better

Comment: @kontur We as graphic designers know it's a pastel filter. To the average person looking at it, it's just some roughed up artwork with a little shading for depth. Look at it from the average consumers perspective.

Comment: @LateralTerminal I think you grossly underestimate the average person’s visual awareness and eye for cheap graphic design, the role of meaning and cultural context for informing design, and the role of a designer as communicator of ideas. Just because OP asked for a filter does not mean you have to suggest a filter if that is nonsense. In my personal experience of 15 years of working as a designer not once has adding a filter made a logo better. Not once.

Comment: @kontur Have you seen ancient hand painted bibles? The effect isn't too far off from that if you want to talk about "early christian scribal culture"https://i.pinimg.com/originals/65/43/fa/6543fa38608d36455a3e61a2bae71fe1.jpg

Comment: @kontur I never said that the filter made it better. And I think you're grossly overestimating what the average person's visual awareness is. We wouldn't have so much comic sans on business vehicle vinyl wraps if people were so graphically visually aware.

Comment: @LateralTerminal The image you link has neither torn edges nor rough texture in the paper visible from chalk drawing. What it does have is line shading from a pen, color filled shapes that occasionally bleed out from their contours, it has inked lettering that has stronger borders where the ink has dried toward the edge of the wet mark, it has colored drop caps and floral interwoven decoration of different color — all of which are a better inspiration that suggesting a beaten, cheap looking, off the shelf texture mimicking the wrong medium. I rest my case about this topic and your answer both.

Comment: @kontur Sure you being an expert in graphic design can tell the difference. The average person who doesn't have 15 years of graphic design experience won't know or care. The average person will just see a sketchy effect that gives it more depth. You're looking way too deep into it.

Comment: Be aware.. everyone and their brother under the age of 40 has a pirated copy of Photoshop or knows someone that does..... the public is fairly aware of what many filters look like and spots them easily at times. You could get away with it 10 years ago. Not so much now days. The younger the demographic the more aware they are. Often Photoshop is actually taught in High School.

Comment: @Scott indeed, my daughter was learning Photoshop in school not long ago (interestingly, one project was web design and the other was page layout... [shudder])

Comment: Yeah.. I'm going to be put out of business by 12 year olds, @Cai :) I just know it.. it's coming.....

Comment: @Scott well it has been discussed over here that should we teach all young adults basics of typography and layout. Which in my opinion is not too much asked.

Comment: Hi all. Thanks for the feedback. Firstly, yes, I'm aware that my post was more within the aesthetic sphere than the technical one. Apologies if that broke any house rules. I'm not a graphic designer. Somewhat obvious. My background is in Art History and  photography. Unfortunately, the client is actually the Trust I work for. Other members asked me to design a logo. Consider this cost cutting. As such, I reluctantly agreed to look into a design.

Comment: My aim was to show the "erosion" of the original 500 y-o cross, to simplify the image too by removing many of the Celtic knots. Pixels: yes, I thought it would be simpler to post the logo that way rather than return to my original Ill. file. It seems the consensus is to return to the original and re-work it. Back to the drawing board.